# Why is there a distinct fundamental cycle for each edge not in the spanning tree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) it says that

> Adding just one edge to a spanning tree will create a cycle; such a cycle is called a fundamental cycle. There is a distinct fundamental cycle for each edge not in the spanning tree; thus, there is a one-to-one correspondence between fundamental cycles and edges not in the spanning tree.

What if i have a graph like this

```
1----2

|    |

3    4
```

and add edge 3-4

```
1----2

|    |

3----4
```

There will be indeed only one new cycle but what if i add 1-4? i will then have 2 more cycles 1-4-3 and 1-4-2.

Where am i wrong ?

i am trying to understand how this formula works

> For a connected graph with V vertices, any spanning tree will have V − 1 edges, and thus, a graph of E edges and one of its spanning trees will have E − V + 1 fundamental cycles

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-2-4 is a new fundamental cycle, but 1-3-4 is not a fundamental cycle. (A fundamental cycle will have only one edge not belonging to the original tree.)

Comment: So i plug in only one new edge at a time and this is how i find the number of fundamental cycles ?

Comment: @Pete42 Adding one edge to a spanning tree will create one cycle; this is a fundamental cycle. If you add multiple edges to a spanning tree, you will create not only fundamental cycles, but also other cycles as well. But the number of fundamental cycles is equal to the number of new edges that you add.